# removing dynamic component warped in dcl-wapper angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm rendering dynamically created components from a component array with `*ngFor` with a `<dcl-wrapper [type]="t"></dcl-wapper>` component described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154552/how-can-i-render-a-component-that-implements-an-interface#37154680)

I'm trying to add a remove button to the component so I could remove the component on button click with `myCompArray.splice(index, 1)` but it allways removes the last one
here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4lhuHF?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker is not working.

Comment: @Vassilis Pits sorry please try again now

Comment: You got your answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index, not the event. The event is `null` because no value was emitted:

```
 (removed)=onRemoved(i)
```

You should also be aware that `[index]=i` updates the `@Input() index;` property on the remaining elements, when an item was removed or added.

Comment: I do pass `comp.instance.removed.subscribe(r => this.onRemoved(this.index));`

Comment: I find your code a bit confusing. You pass the index through the whole application but you already have it available where you need it anyway. I think the main confusion is (as I already added to my answer) that `@Input() index;` gets updated by `ngFor` when an item is removed.

Comment: I write out in the console which index I'm going to remove and even I get 0 it removes the last one

Comment: It doesn't remove the last one, but `*ngFor` updates the `index` and the first item (previously the 2nd) gets `[index]="0"` and the 2nd (previously the 3rd) `[index]="1"` assigned and then there is no item with `[index]="2"` anymore.

Comment: I know the index changes, its the position in array; but look at my updated plunker you'll c that that initially each text box has a different value so you can see when you remove the middle one that last one will fall off

Comment: I see it now. I tried to figure out what's going on but failed so far.

Comment: It seems to be related to how equality works. If you use different types `[C1, C2, C3]` it behaves differently or if you wrap the types in object literals http://plnkr.co/edit/tNXJAt?p=preview. Deleting at the end works but at the beginning or in the middle, all elements after the deleted are recreated.