# Dynamic Component Loading with Webpack Code Splitting

Tags: angular, webpack

In order to load dynamic componets i use materail tab as follows:

```
<md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex" *ngIf="tabs && tabs.length > 0">
    <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
        <template md-tab-label>
            {{tab.title}}
            <span class="k-icon k-i-close mat-tab-close" (click)="close(tab)"></span>
        </template>
        <dcl-wrapper [type]="tab.component"></dcl-wrapper>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I want to load components into this tab from different modules. Loading process is done with **dcl-wrapper** as it is suggested in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154680/5285133

I give the seperate module component to the dcl-wrapper with webpack code splitting strategy.

```
require.ensure(["../../dmy/dmy.module"], (reqire : any) => {
    let cmp = require("../../dmy/page/page2")["Page2"];
    this.tabs.push({ title: "--", component: cmp });
    this.selectedTabIndex = this.tabs.length - 1;
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
}, "dmy");
```

But i get "**No component factory found for Page2. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?**" error.

I also tried to load seperate module components with SystemJsNgModuleLoader this way:

```
this._loader.load('../../dmy/dmy.module#DMYModule').then((factory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
    console.log(factory);
});
```

It gives this error:

Error: **Cannot find module '../../dmy/dmy.module'.?    at webpackEmptyContext**

Since i use tab component instead of routing, lazy load is not the solution that i want. So, i look for a way to get the instance of seperate module component.

Do you have any suggestion how i can load a seperate module and its components dynamically?

Comment: `No component factory found for Page2.` did you add this component to `entryComponents` array? If so then in which module(or component) have you added it?

Comment: `Cannot find module '../../dmy/dmy.module'.` Maybe you need to try other paths i.e `app/dmy/dmy.module#DMYModule`

Comment: How does your `DMYModule` look like?

Comment: 1. Adding Page2 or any other components to entryComponents is not the way webpack advices.  
2. I tried many path variations but this is nothing to do with path, the problem is that SystemJsNgModuleLoader can not be used with webpack I think.  
3. DMYModule is a simple module with some test pages in it.

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` requires compiled component and it can be achieved only adding this component to `entryComponents` array. This way angulat will compile factory for this component and hold link to this factory inside `ComponentFactoryResolver`

Comment: Then, how can i load components dynamically with code splitting and without adding components to entryComponents.

Comment: `SystemJsNgModuleLoader` can work with webpack2. It can understand `System.import` but it is deprecated as far as i know

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2302

Comment: Do you have your own webpack config?

Comment: Yes i have a webpack config one that is taken from one of the git start projects.

Comment: System.import("../../dmy/dmy.module").then((data: any) => {
     console.log(data); //this is DMYModule
      // how can i get Page2
});

Comment: The same thing angular does in build-in directive `ngComponentOutlet` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.0-beta.0/packages/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.ts#L99

Comment: My example was broken so i fixed it https://plnkr.co/edit/85zrrDdJoStf0mz7QIHT?p=preview

Comment: I still get no component factory found error. This is my webpack config, http://take.ms/uZNYz . I compiled with npm run prepublish. Is it ok?

Comment: No. You need to compile it via https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.1.0-beta.0/packages/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.ts#L69

Comment: Thank you very much, i will share the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.import("../../dmy/dmy.module.js")
            .then((module: any) => {
                return module["DMYModule"];
            }).then((type: any) => {
                return this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(type);
            }).then((moduleWithFactories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
                const factory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find((x: any) => x.componentType.name === "Page1"); 
                this.tabs.push({ title: "--", component: factory["componentType"], factory: factory });
                this.selectedTabIndex = this.tabs.length - 1;
                this._cdr.detectChanges();
            });
```